# How to tell if a tree branch overhangs a Sukkah site

Tags: product-recommendation, how-to, sukkah, trees

I'm trying to think of a practical and inexpensive way to tell at what point tree branches overhang our patio to know which parts can be used for a *sukkah*.  The best ideas I've come up with that seem more precise than just eyeballing it (the branches are quite high) is to buy a drone and attach a long string to it, or use a level to point a laser straight up at the branches to see if they overhang. (Would a device like [this](https://smile.amazon.com/Qooltek-Multipurpose-measure-Adjusted-Standard/dp/B00PQ4PJYC/ref=sr_1_4?s=hi&ie=UTF8&qid=1503881374&sr=1-4&keywords=level) work?)  Any reasonable suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a very complicated way to do it to me. Why not tie a long rope to the branch and see where the rope hits the ground? +1, by the way.

Comment: @ezra He said very high up. Presumably he doesn’t own a fire truck that he can reach those branches. :)

Comment: @DonielF - LOL. I guess I overlooked that in his question. :)

Comment: I’m not sure what’s wrong with the laser pointer idea. Just grab a cheap one from your local Dollar Tree and check the branches at night, when you’ll be able to see the light on the laser pointer.

Comment: If you attach a string to a drone, attach a plummet to the string.

Comment: @DonielF Would the laser interfere with planes flying overhead?

Comment: Eyeballing it would be fine as long as you press your face against the inside wall. Then if you don't see any branches overhead, you are certain it's fine.

Comment: @Ploni Not if they hit tree branches. Just don’t point them in neighbors’ windows to scare them into thinking someone’s aiming a gun at them and you should be fine. If you’re using a little red laser pointer the light would probably diffuse before it even hit the plane; it’s the green ones that are the issues.

Comment: You can probably do it with some shadow trigonometry.

Comment: @user6591's idea may work for determining whether the tree encroaches at all, but won't help for determining what area in the sukka an encroaching tree covers.

Comment: That device looks phenomenal. Any reason to assume it won't be good?

Comment: @Eliyahu For some reason (perhaps the manufacturer lacked the foresight to realize this use) the "bubble levels" don't include a side-to-side level, which means while one can perhaps tell it's not tilted toward the ruler, it's harder to tell if it's tilted perpendicular to the ruler.

Comment: @Eliyahu Which isn't to say one couldn't attach an additional level themselves, or contrive to hang the entire contraption as a fulcrum (or a simpler laser).

Comment: Do we know for sure that the criteria "under a tree" means "vertical"?   Because one could make a case that the issue is to not sit in the shade of the tree -- something a lot easier to check.

Comment: I asked my rav a question similar to yours last Succot. I think the maximum height is 10 amot (I'll try to re-check with him next time I see him. Y'know, Succot and Purim don't exactly "mix" ;-) At any rate, it's not overly high, I gather, that you couldn't go on a ladder and get a long yardstick to measure this.

Comment: Whatever method you choose, don't forget that the trees are going to grow.

Comment: @Nic " something a lot easier to check" - I think it would be much **harder** to check that. Different times of the day cause different shadow lengths, and thus, different amounts of shade.

Comment: @nic yes we do see MB and Biur Halacha to OC 626

Comment: It should be noted that it is very hard to imagine this making a significant difference halacha lemaaseh,

Comment: @רבותמחשבות how so?

Comment: @Loewian Most people in situations like this where tree branches might be growing over a sukkah would not necessarily have men sitting under those portions (which would be considered under Pasul Sechach).  I find it hard to imagine a situation where it might be a case that would actually Passul the entire Sukkah (i.e. over most of it) where you would be unsure if it is hanging over it or not.  If that case exists, practically, most of the time you can probably find some other place to put it.  Also, there are Shitos which are more meikel if you do not have another place and a kosher sukkah.

Comment: @Loewian read through OC 626 with all of the Poskim for more details...  Just to be clear, I'm not saying this question isn't an excellent question - it is, I upvoted it too, but it is practically vary rarely appliccable to Passul a Sukkah

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Huh.   Learned something new.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות Even if there's clearly a kosher sukka there, it is important to know which areas within one can live in to fulfill the mitzva.

Comment: @IsaacMoses true, but I would assume that in most cases, it is easy enough to avoid the portion of the sukkah that might be covered by a tree, even without an exact determination of where that is.

Answer (score 1):

go outside, take a strong flashlight, lay it on a flat surface underneath the tree and see if it hits the branches or just disappears into the blackness of the night.

Comment: The beam of a flashlight (as opposed to a laser) spreads outward, which means that it illuminates even nonproblematic branches that are not directly overhead.

Comment: They do have flastlights which is a beam flashlight

Answer (score 1):

Here are some simple methods to determine if it's hanging over the sukkah, and how much space it's taking.

**Method one**

*This method is assuming that the sukkah is already built, and you're just trying to see if any part of the tree is hanging in. Otherwise, see method two, below.*

The simplest and cheapest way, would be to look up at the tree while pressing yourself to the inside wall of the sukah. This way, if you see the branch, that would tell you that it's directly on top of the sukkah. But if you don't see it, obviously it's not actually on top.

**Method two**

For this one, make sure the floor of the sukah is flat. And not on a slant.

Get a good laser¹, put it on the floor of the sukkah facing up, and move it around while still facing strait up, and see if it hits the tree.

If it does hit the tree, move it around to determine how big of an area it's taking up.

If it doesn't hit the tree, that would determine that the tree is not hanging directly over the sukkah.

---

The drone idea is extra and unnecessary work. The laser will give you an accurate answer.

The product you mentioned in your question, is reviewed in this [video](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01M22MK3J) on Amazon, where the reviewer says that while the product is amazing for indoor purposes, it barely has any use for outdoors being that the laser is not seen past a few feet in daylight. (Great idea otherwise)

<sub>1. You can use any accurate laser for this. Try to get one that has a flat bottom, so that you can stand it up accurately.</sub>

Comment: Is there any reason the product couldn't be used effectively at night?

Comment: @Yez you could probably use it in case of "emergency" but at night it's not ideal anyway because it's too dark to see the tree... And if you shine a light to see the tree, then you won't see the beam of your product cuz it's too light for it...

Comment: If the product is "amazing" indoors, then I assume it works well in a comparable level of light outdoors. So go outside at dusk, or whenever it is only as light as indoors, and you'll see the tree and you'll see the beam.

Comment: @Yez i don't own this product. So i don't have a way to test it. My comment was on OP's question "would this product work" all I'm saying is, you might not want to spend the money on a product that might not work outside. Is it possible to make it work? Maybe, but I'd suggest using any other laser, just in case this one is a waste it your money